# Share buttons issue

Tags: css, css-transitions, share-button

I have this problem with the code below, I made made this code where "div" expands from right to left on hover, I need that expansion to come back when the mouse is off of the bottom area (48x48px)…

```css
height: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #ebebeb;
    position: relative;
}


/* --- Shere buttons --- */

.share {
    position: absolute;
    top: 270px;
    right: 970px;
    width:161px;
    height:auto;
}

.top-share {
    width: 145px;
    border-left: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-top: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #777;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 46px;
}

.top-share span {
    background: url(img/share-img.png) no-repeat #f7f7f7;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a {display: block;}

.share-botton-fb, .share-botton-tw, .share-botton-gp, .share-botton-inst, .share-botton-pin {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #ebebeb no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: 113px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s, left .3s;
}

.fb {
    width: 48px; height:48px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(img/facebook.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.fb:hover {background-image: url(img/facebook-hover.png); background-color: #3b5998; }
.share-botton-fb:hover { background: url(img/fb-text.png) center #3b5998 no-repeat; width: 161px; left: 0;}

.tw {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    background: url(img/twitter.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.tw:hover {background-image: url(img/twitter-hover.png); background-color: #2ba9e1;}
.share-botton-tw:hover { background: url(img/tw-text.png) center #2ba9e1 no-repeat; width: 161px; left: 0;}

.gp {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(img/google-plus.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
}
.gp:hover {background-image: url(img/google-plus-hover.png); background-color: #dd4b39;}
.share-botton-gp:hover { background: url(img/gp-text.png) center #dd4b39 no-repeat; width: 161px; left: 0;}

.inst {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(img/instagram.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.inst:hover {background-image: url(img/instagram-hover.png); background-color: #517fa4;}
.share-botton-inst:hover { background: url(img/inst-text.png) center #517fa4 no-repeat; width:161px; left:0;}

.pin {
    width: 48px; height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(img/pinterest.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.pin:hover {background-image: url(img/pinterest-hover.png); background-color: #d73532;}
.share-botton-pin:hover { background: url(img/pin-text.png) center #d73532 no-repeat; width: 161px; left: 0;}
 
/* --- Share buttons END --- */
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="share">
        <div class="top-share">icons below <span></span></div>
        <div class="share-botton-fb"><a href="#"><div class="fb">FB</div></a></div>
        <div class="share-botton-tw"><a href="#"><div class="tw">TW</div></a></div>
        <div class="share-botton-gp"><a href="#"><div class="gp">GP</div></a></div>
        <div class="share-botton-inst"><a href="#"><div class="inst">INST</div></a></div>
        <div class="share-botton-pin"><a href="#"><div class="pin">PIN</div></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But it does return back to the original state... Do you have this issue when you run the snippet from your question?

Comment: if you put the mouse to the expantion section the icon hover is turning off (fb,tw,gpt ecc)

Comment: I think you want to add a delay in the transition so that it lasts when u put mouse off the icon..am i right?

Comment: my english is not very good, but i'll try to explain: when you put the mouse to the botton (FB) its expands to the left and its ok. But when you move the mouse on expandet area the hover from the botton is turning off but its remains on expandet area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some incomplete CSS code in the beginning of your snippet, which I'm going to omit.

If I got your issue right, the problem is that the grey area with FB, TW and so on is not highlighted when you move your mouse to the highlighted area on the left. That is because you're not hovering this div on the right anymore.

What you need is to add a selector for when you hover on the left-side div, the right-side should also be highlighted. So, for example, you need to change the selector `.fb:hover` to `.fb:hover, .share-botton-fb:hover .fb`.

I also fixed the CSS indentation and added a missing closing div in the HTML.

I had to comment out `position: absolute;` of `.share` because then you wouldn't see the div in the snippet. But on your website you probably need to uncomment it.

Here's the code:

```css
/* --- Shere buttons --- */

.share {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 270px;
    right: 970px;
    width:161px;
    height:auto;
}

.top-share{
    width: 145px;
    border-left: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-top: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #777;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 46px;
}

.top-share span {
    background: url(img/share-img.png) no-repeat  #f7f7f7;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a {display:block;}

.share-botton-fb, .share-botton-tw, .share-botton-gp, .share-botton-inst, .share-botton-pin {
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background:#ebebeb no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    left:113px;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s, left .3s;
}


.fb {
    width:48px; height:48px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(img/facebook.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.fb:hover, .share-botton-fb:hover .fb {background-image:url(img/facebook-hover.png); background-color:#3b5998; }
.share-botton-fb:hover { background: url(img/fb-text.png) center #3b5998 no-repeat; width:161px; left:0;}


.tw {
    width:48px; height:48px;
    position:relative;
    right:0px;
    background:url(img/twitter.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.tw:hover, .share-botton-tw:hover .tw {background-image:url(img/twitter-hover.png); background-color:#2ba9e1;}
.share-botton-tw:hover { background: url(img/tw-text.png) center #2ba9e1 no-repeat; width:161px; left:0;}


.gp {
    width:48px; height:48px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(img/google-plus.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
}
.gp:hover, .share-botton-gp:hover .gp {background-image:url(img/google-plus-hover.png); background-color:#dd4b39;}
.share-botton-gp:hover { background: url(img/gp-text.png) center #dd4b39 no-repeat; width:161px; left:0;}

.inst {
    width:48px; height:48px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(img/instagram.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
}
.inst:hover, .share-botton-inst:hover .inst {background-image:url(img/instagram-hover.png); background-color:#517fa4;}
.share-botton-inst:hover { background: url(img/inst-text.png) center #517fa4 no-repeat; width:161px; left:0;}

.pin {
    width:48px; height:48px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(img/pinterest.png) no-repeat center #ebebeb;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
}
.pin:hover, .share-botton-pin:hover .pin {background-image:url(img/pinterest-hover.png); background-color:#d73532;}
.share-botton-pin:hover { background: url(img/pin-text.png) center #d73532 no-repeat; width:161px; left:0;}
    
/* --- Share buttons END --- */
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="share">
        <div class="top-share">icons below <span></span></div>

        <div class="share-botton-fb"><a href="#"><div class="fb">FB</div></a></div>
        <div class="share-botton-tw"><a href="#"><div class="tw">TW</div></a></div>
        <div class="share-botton-gp"><a href="#"><div class="gp">GP</div></a></div>
        <div class="share-botton-inst"><a href="#"><div class="inst">INST</div></a></div>
        <div class="share-botton-pin"><a href="#"><div class="pin">PIN</div></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT !!! its been a few hour that i was trying to fix it !!! thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please don't forget to accept the answer.